# How can I deploy deploy my local Java "Web Application"

Tags: java, jsp, gradle, deployment, jetty

all!

I'm currently working on a project for a friend of mine. I'm using a WebView for the GUI so that I can use web technologies instead of Swing or JavaFX (I know that WebView is part of JavaFX).

I'm also using JSP, so I'm using jetty (will change to gretty soon) as the servlet container/web server. My friend needs to store data somewhere, so I'm using SQLite as the database.

Currently I just build the project through gradle, but I'm unsure how I can deploy this (as an executable jar for example) for my friend. I need to somehow execute jetty and SQLite before the actual front-end, but I'm unsure of how to do that.

I imagine I should make a driver file and execute those programs from main, but I'm unsure of how I would go about doing that. If this is the case, could someone go into detail as to how to approach it this way?

I'm also not turned off by out of the ordinary solutions! If it works, that's good enough for me!

Any help at all would be immensely appreciated! Thank you all very much!

Comment: I suppose my post may not have been totally clear. The application is 100% local. This will not be an application deployed on the web. I just used web technologies because I felt it would make constructing the GUI easier.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "somehow execute jetty and SQLite before the actual front-end"? I actually do understand where your problem is. As you are using a WebView, your probably have an instance of Application as your starting point. There you can place all initialization actions into the init() method and you then start the GUI (WebView) in the start() method. So, where is your problem?

Comment: Maybe you want a [self-contained application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) packaged using the [javafx gradle plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin).

Comment: @mipa Ahh I see. So override init. That makes sense. Now the part I don't understand is how would I start the webserver (jetty) in the init method? Once again thank you for your time!

Comment: I have never used jetty myself but a simple google search for "start embedded jetty" provides several tutorials which seem to describe what you want to do.

Comment: @mipa Wonderful, thank you!